# Is there a general way to prove a representation is irreducible?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I can see how to go about proving reducible representations by finding projection matrices, but I don't know how to prove the inexistence of these projectors to prove a representation is irreducible. Is there a way to do this? I'm working on simply proving the $D(e)=1, D(a)=e^{(2i\pi/3)},D(b)=e^{(4i\pi/3)}$ an irreducible representation of $Z_3$, given by the multiplication table:

$$
  \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|}
      \backslash
    & e
    & a
    & b
    \\
    \hline
      e
    & e
    & a
    & b
    \\
    \hline
      a
    & a
    & b
    & e
    \\
    \hline
      b
    & b
    & e
    & a
    \\
    \hline
  \end{array}
$$

Thank you!

Comment: the representation has dimension $1$, any representation of dimension $1$ is irreducible

Comment: an answer to your more general question can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111404/algorithm-to-check-is-representation-irreducible-algorithm-to-decompose-the-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A commutative group will always contain $\vert G \vert$ 1-dimensional irreducible representations since $\sum_{i=1}^{\vert G\vert}1^2 = \vert G\vert$ this is due to every conjugacy class being unique as consequence of commutativity $a^{-1}b{a} = b$ thus the action by conjugation only yields $b$ as the unique member of the conjugacy class $b$.

This is strongly connected to character theory and a good article to start with is the associated to Dirichlet characters of multiplicative groups of integers mod $n$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character#A_few_character_tables